# Internationalisation and Localisation with Ionic 6 and Angular 15 best practices

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to understand how to make an app created with Angular 15 and Ionic 6 ready for different countries (internationalisation and localisation).
There is a way to use the default Angular approach with Ionic? If it is so will I need to create different apps for the Stores, one for each supported locale-id?

I hope the question is clear, thanks in advance to whom will spend some time to help me.

Looking around I saw that Angular has its way to do it https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview) but it seems that when the application is packed for the Apple or Google store it doesn't work very well. The other approach I've found is using a package `ngx-translate` (http://www.ngx-translate.com). In this approach it's not clear how to localise currencies and date time format for example.
I'd like to have the web application ready to be released in different countries. I'll start to publish the web app on a website and then I'd like to publish a version in the Apple and Google store without keeping different codebase.